# Show taxonomy only when logged in

Tags: taxonomy-terms, users

I have a content type with two taxonomy terms: "Intern" and "Non-Intern"
I want the items with "Intern" to only be visible when logged in. How do I achieve that?

Comment: which version of drupal are you using 6 0r 7 ?

Comment: I'm using version 7

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Taxonomy access](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access) module to access control for user `role`.

> - Automatically controls access to nodes (based on their taxonomy    terms).
> - Configuration page for each user role.
> - Three node access permission types: View, Update, Delete.
> - Two term access types: View tag, Add tag.